# How to randomly pick k items from a list of n size in python

Tags: python, algorithm

I want to know how to randomly pick k items from a list of n size for ALL possible combinations.

> For example, let A = [1, 2, 3, 4] and K = 3. Then it should return [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], and [2, 3, 4].

Comment: What part of this is random?

Comment: Any attempt from your side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations). For example:

```
>>> my_list = A = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> k = 3

>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> list(combinations(my_list, k))
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the ordering inside the results matters you might use [itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) to get all permutations as well - putting them into a set removes duplicates stemming from duplicate numbers in your list

```
import itertools

n = 3
my_list =  [1, 2, 3, 2 ,1]

print( set(itertools.permutations(my_list, n))) # or list, see below
```

Output:

```
{(1, 2, 1), (3, 1, 2), (2, 3, 2), (1, 3, 2), (3, 1, 1), (3, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), 
 (1, 1, 3), (2, 2, 1), (2, 1, 1), (1, 3, 1), (2, 3, 1), (1, 2, 3), (1, 1, 2), ...} 
 # with set: 17 items

[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 1), (1, 3, 2), (1, 3, 2), (1, 3, 1), (1, 2, 2), 
 (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 1, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 1, 2), ...] 
 # with list: 60 items
```

Difference between permutations and combinations:

```
# permutations - based on all values on any position in the resulttuple
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 1), (1, 3, 2), (1, 3, 2), (1, 3, 1), (1, 2, 2), (1
, 2, 3), (1, 2, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 1, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 1, 2), (2, 1
, 1), (2, 3, 1), (2, 3, 2), (2, 3, 1), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 3), (2, 2, 1), (2, 1, 1
), (2, 1, 3), (2, 1, 2), (3, 1, 2), (3, 1, 2), (3, 1, 1), (3, 2, 1), (3, 2, 2),
(3, 2, 1), (3, 2, 1), (3, 2, 2), (3, 2, 1), (3, 1, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 1, 2), (2,
 1, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 1, 1), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 3), (2, 2, 1), (2, 3, 1), (2, 3,
 2), (2, 3, 1), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 1, 3), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 1, 2)
, (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 2), (1, 3, 1), (1, 3, 2), (1, 3, 2), (1, 2, 1), (
1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3)]

# combinations - based on position in source list not on value order in tuple preserved
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 1), (1, 3, 2), (1, 3, 1), (1, 2, 1), (2, 3, 2), (2
, 3, 1), (2, 2, 1), (3, 2, 1)]
```

Press any key to continue . . .